# How to get media content in typoscript assigned to the current page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have 3 pics that are assigned to my page and I am trying to put them into a variable in typoscript.

Here is my code:

```
temp.pics = FILES
temp.pics {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = page:uid
    fieldName = media
  }
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:originalUid
    altText.data = file:current:title
    wrap = <li>|</li>
  }
stdWrap.wrap = <ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">|</ul>
}

page.10 {
  variables {
    pics < temp.pics
  }
}
```

And in my HTML layout I only get:

```
<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery"></ul>
```

Does anybody have an idea why it is empty?

Comment: Try to find out if the `FILES` cObject finds anything to render, or if the `IMAGES` object just renders empty strings for everything. You could do so by replacing the `IMAGE` with something like `renderObj = TEXT renderObj.value = foobar`. If there is no output, the `FILES` cObject does not find anything, otherwise the `IMAGE` cObject is not configured correctly.

Comment: @Jost, yes, it's empty. And i checked out table 'pages' in phpmyadmin, media field is also empty (0). It's strange, because i have some assigned media to my page.